# Geotools Error: LWGEOM_estimsted_extent : couldn't locate table, appears when adding a layer

Tags: geotools

I am using `version 8.0-M2` of `geotools`. Each time I try adding a `layer` to `mapContent` using `mapContent.addLayer`,

I have a warning that reads:

> "WARNING: Failed to use ST_Estimated_Extent, falling back on envelope
>   aggregation ",

and an error that says:

> " org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: LWGEOM_estimated_extent:
>   couldn't locate table within current schema".

Though, this doesn't effect the way my application works, I want to get rid of the exception. Can someone please help me with this?